# Add group names based on several variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a variable containing group names determined based on four other variables. Let me create a dummy table to put this into a better perspective:

| classwork | stream | people | others | grouping1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| High | High | High | High | Group1 |
| High | High | High | High | Group1 |
| High | High | High | Low | Group2 |
| High | High | High | Low | Group2 |
| High | High | Low | Low | Group3 |

The name of group is based on the data, obtained using this code

```
DATA.RH.TAM %>%
  group_by(C.level, S.level, P.level, O.level) %>%
  summarize(index = sum(index))
```

I would like to also create another variable (grouping2) based on only three other variables later.

```
DATA.RH.TAM %>%
  group_by(C.level, S.level, P.level) %>%
  summarize(index = sum(index))
```

Your help is much appreciated.

The following is my dataset:

```
DATA.RH.TAM <- structure(c("High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", 
            "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
            "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
            "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", 
            "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", 
            "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", 
            "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", 
            "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", 
            "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", 
            "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
            "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", 
            "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
            "High", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", 
            "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", "Low", 
            "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", 
            "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
            "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
            "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
            "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", 
            "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
            "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", 
            "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", 
            "Low", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", 
            "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
            "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "High", 
            "High", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
            "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", 
            "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
            "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", 
            "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", 
            "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", 
            "High", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", 
            "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", 
            "High", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "Low", "High", 
            "Low", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", 
            "High", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", 
            "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High", "1", 
            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
            "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), .Dim = c(156L, 
                                                                                  5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("classwork", "stream", "people", 
                                                                                                                "others", "index")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(DATA.RH.TAM)
DT[, grouping1 := paste0("group", .GRP), by = .(classwork, stream, people, others)]
DT[, grouping2 := paste0("group", .GRP), by = .(classwork, stream, people)]
#      classwork stream people others index grouping1 grouping2
#   1:      High   High   High   High     1    group1    group1
#   2:      High    Low   High   High     1    group2    group2
#   3:      High   High   High   High     1    group1    group1
#   4:       Low    Low   High   High     1    group3    group3
#   5:      High   High   High    Low     1    group4    group1
# ---                                                         
# 152:      High   High   High   High     1    group1    group1
# 153:      High    Low   High   High     1    group2    group2
# 154:       Low    Low   High   High     1    group3    group3
# 155:      High   High   High   High     1    group1    group1
# 156:      High   High   High   High     1    group1    group1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, you can use `mutate` with `case_when`. In comparison with `data.table`, you need to specify all the combinations though. (Please note that I have only used the head of your dataset.)

```
DATA.RH.TAM <- head(as.data.frame(DATA.RH.TAM))

DATA.RH.TAM <- DATA.RH.TAM %>%
mutate(Grouping = case_when
       ((classwork == "High" & stream == "High" & people == "High" & others == "High") ~ "Group 1",
        (classwork == "High" & stream == "Low" & people == "High" & others == "High") ~ "Group 2",
        (classwork == "Low" & stream == "Low" & people == "High" & others == "High") ~ "Group 3",
        (classwork == "High" & stream == "High" & people == "High" & others == "Low") ~ "Group 4",
        (classwork == "High" & stream == "Low" & people == "High" & others == "High") ~ "Group 5",
        FALSE ~ "Group X"
       ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse way

```
library(tidyverse)  
df <- DATA.RH.TAM %>% as_tibble()
df %>%
  group_by(classwork,stream, people, others) %>%
  mutate(group1 = paste0("Group",cur_group_id())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(classwork,stream, people) %>%
  mutate(group2 = paste0("Group",cur_group_id()))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This method is promising, but I do not know what it does not work for my case.

Comment: You need Dplyr v1.0 or higher for cur_group_id. Do post the error if that's not the issue.